# перевод каждого элемента стринг в инт

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, int

что нужно написать в цикле чтобы перевести каждый элемент стринга в инт и прибавить его в 'c'

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
int i,c=0;
string s;
cin>>s;
for(i=0; i<s.size(); i++){
s[i] += c;
}
cout<<c;
return 0;
}
```

пример 123123

ответ: 12

Comment: Заменить `s[i] += c;` на `c+=s[i]-'0'`... И молиться, чтоб в строке, кроме цифр, ничего не было.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Чтобы на ввод шли только цифры, а остальное отбрасывалось делайте следующее.
После `cin >> s;` просто добавьте 2 строки.
Это: `cin.clear();` и `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');`. При этом обязательно добавьте библиотеку: `#include <limits>`.
А так действуйте как Вам посоветовал @Harry.